# C++ function split string into words

Tags: c++, string, function, split, words

im trying to write a function in c++ that splits my string test into separate words in an array. i cant seem to the stuff in loop right... anyone got any ideas? it should print "this"

```
void app::split() {

    string test = "this is my testing string.";

    char* tempLine = new char[test.size() + 1];
    strcpy(tempLine, test.c_str());

    char* singleWord;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tempLine); i++) {

        if (tempLine[i] == ' ') {
            words[wordCount] = singleWord;
            delete[]singleWord;
        }

            else {
            singleWord[i] = tempLine[i];
            wordCount++;

            }

    }

    cout << words[0];
    delete[]tempLine;


}
```

Comment: This is kind of reinventing the wheel. Why not using the default behavior of string streams?

Comment: Two comments: (a) what is stopping you from debugging this yourself ? (you know how to use a debugger, right ?) and (b) if this is supposed to be C++ then why use bare pointers and C-style programming ?

Comment: sizeof(tempLine) is equivalent to use sizeof(char*) which is 4 (32bits) in x86 architecture. You can get the length of the string using strlen(tempLine). Also I'd recommend you to use a std::vector<char> instead of a raw char[] array.

Comment: im not familiar with c++. i just started programing in it a few days ago...

Comment: Also you can use string::substr() function to get parts of the original string.

Comment: Do you want to learn the fundamentals (e.g. arrays and pointers) or the advanced features (e.g. standard containers and `stringstream`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to display words from string use:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
//..
   string test= "this is my testing string.";
        istringstream iss(test);
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
                 istream_iterator<string>(),
                 ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

else to process those words uses `std::vector` of `std::string`

```
     std::vector<std::string> vec;

        istringstream iss(test);
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
                 istream_iterator<string>(),
                 back_inserter(vec));
```

Comment: the istringstream is really cool. but i want to store them in an array or something so i can print the words in different algorithms

Comment: You can just initialize the vector from the iterators: `vector<string>vec {istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>()};`