# error: Iso c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [c++], splitting sentence into words

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to split the sentence into words by checking the characters from the string one by one.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    getline(cin,a);
    string word = "";
    for(int i=0;i=a.size();i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==" ") //error iso here
        {
            cout<<word<<endl;
            word="";
        }
        else
        {
            word+=a[i];
        }
        cout<<word<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add a Tag to specify what C* language you are using?

Comment: I have edited it! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Would this SO match work for you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137617/c-function-split-string-into-words

Comment: The SO "Related" list to your question also looks promising to me, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281962/c11-sorting-list-using-lambda?rq=1